# Using dispatch_async to load images in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uicollectionview, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using Parse to store images. I am trying to load the images asynchronously so it does not interfere with the `collectionView` scroll. I am new to using `dispatch_async`, and am not so sure how to properly implement it. I've also looked into lazy load, but I thought this would work. But it doesn't, and the `collectionView` scroll is choppy. Thanks

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    albumImageCell *cell = (albumImageCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[albumImageCell alloc]init];
    }

    PFObject *temp = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFFile *file = [temp objectForKey:@"image"];

    if (cell.hasImage == FALSE) {
        dispatch_async(imageQueue, ^{
            NSData *data = [file getData];
                if (data) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        cell.hasImage = TRUE;
                    });

                }
        });
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: There are problems with this code beyond choppiness. A cell can get reused while images are being loaded in the background. You could wind up with the wrong image connected to a particular cell. I think the best solution I've seen to this issue to create an asynchronous UIImageView class that loads in the background on its own. I don't know if this particular one is good, but you might give it a try: https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

Comment: @EricS Yes this has happened before. Do you think i would be able to load and set the image in my custom `collectionViewCell` file instead of subclass `UIImageView`?

Comment: Sure, but you'll have to handle the case when the cell gets reused by implementing the `prepareForReuse` method. You'll want to cancel the existing network request, or at least ignore the result, and create a new one. Remember that the second request may return before the first one - there's no guaranty they'll come back in any particular order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `UIImage +imageWithData` method blocks the main thread a bit.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

So these lines should be as the following.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    cell.imageView.image = image;
```

Besides, UIImage doesn't decode the image immediately till the UIImage object is actually shown or rendered. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19251240/629118. Thus, the following code is one of the best way to get rid of choppy scrolling.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1,1));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), [image CGImage]);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    cell.imageView.image = image;
```

Comment: Our solution to this problem was to create a CGImageRef on the background thread instead of a UIImage and pass the CGImageRef to the main thread. The main thread would create a UIImage from the CGImageRef, which was pretty fast. (UIImage also wasn't thread-safe in earlier versions of iOS, so we got in the habit of never using them on secondary threads)