# iOS Data Storage Rejection

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, data-storage

My app got rejected because Apple found that on launch and/or content download, my app stores 14.18 MB.

Now I'm trying to skip backup of all the images and sounds I use in the game.

So far, I made a folder called "Resources" in my app folder itself, looking like this: [App Folder Scrshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0uh2dgzhr66mu1e/Screenshot%202014-05-01%2012.41.45.png)

What I did in AppDelegate.m is next:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
}
```

This isn't working.

I have 2 questions:

1)Am I doing the right thing from the start? Should I put all the images and sounds in folder called Resources, and then skipBackup for the entire folder or should I put them somewhere else?
If yes, then where?
(I saw over internet people talking about "Documents" folder...but I don't know what that folder is nor where to find it.

2)If I could put everything in "Resources" folder, how to I reach that folder from the code? How do I make URL to that folder, from Xcode itself?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you saw on internet about this document folder - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709705/read-text-file-in-document-folder-iphone-sdk

Comment: From your image, the "Resources" is a group not a physical folder.  Show us the entire Apple's rejection reason, perhaps we can help.

Comment: This is their rejection reason: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r48ymxvzhgsn5oc/Screenshot%202014-05-01%2014.02.50.png

Answer (score 0):

You should deliver the content with your app. downloading the content on first launch is not a good idea due to the connection issue if user is on 3G/Edge.

the document directory is on the device, a folder under your app, and its created by ios automatically. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

getting files from resource folder is easy [files from resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12205868/883954)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before ! The problem is not the size of what you store, it is *where* you store it. My guess is that you store your file in `NSDocumentDirectory`, which is bad because this directory should only be used to store data that the user created himself (documents, photo, etc). Adding the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` is not enough. When it happened to me, I changed `NSDocumentDirectory` to `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` and my app got approved.

**UPDATE**

It is best if you first create a subdirectory in your `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` to store your file there.

Your methods should look like something like :

```
- (NSURL *) applicationDocumentsDirectory{
    NSString *appSupportDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    appSupportDir = [appSupportDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAppDirectory"];
    return [NSURL URLWithString:appSupportDir];
}
```

And don't forget to create the directory first :

```
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] isDirectory:NULL]) {
        NSError *error = nil;        
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    }
```

Comment: Hi Emilie. I think we are on the track here.
Thing is, I never put anything anywhere..or I never specifically told program where to put what. So I guess it's using some defaults.

This is the second app im publishing to an app store. I had no problem with the first one, and they are pretty much similarly made. So I never specified where to put which data, but somehow my first app is storing only 0.5mb on iCloud and this one stores 12Mb.

Can you tell me where should I specify which files are stored where?
is it in AppDelegate.m or somewhere else? Any tutorial would do as well :)

Comment: @Stebra Can you post the code of your method `[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]` ?

Comment: Here it is:
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

Comment: when I replace NSDocumentDirectory with NSApplicationSupportDirectory in [self applicationDocumentsDirectory], I get this error: Error excluding Application Support from backup Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 ... "The operation couldn't be completed. No such file or directory"}
That's when I comment out assertion line.

Comment: If I don't comment out assertion line, I get the following error:"Assertion failed: ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]), function -[AppDelegate addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:], file /Users/stefanbrankovic/Desktop/FessorsLounge 2/FessorsLounge/AppDelegate.m, line 54."

Comment: @Stebra pretty sure it's because xCode don't want to remove complete support directory from backup. In my code, I store my files in a subfolder in `NSApplicationSupportDirectory`. See my update in my comment for more details

Comment: Emilie, This thread is slowly becoming too long. So instead of answering here, I started a new question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408210/error-excluding-applicationsupportdirectory-from-backup

Please, check it out :)