# Error excluding ApplicationSupportDirectory from Backup

Tags: ios, app-store, nsdocumentdirectory

MY App got rejected because it backsUp too much data to iCloud.

In order to solve the problem, I have to put all of my files in a new directory, located in ApplicationSupportDirectory.
I am not managing to do it so far and I cannot figure out what seems to be the problem.

This is my code so far:

AppDelegate.m class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

NSString* string = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] absoluteString];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:string  isDirectory:NULL]) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:string 
withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"I'm not even making your stupid dir");
    }
}
[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]];
return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{

NSString *appSupportDir =   
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,  
YES) lastObject];
appSupportDir = [appSupportDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAppDirectory"];
NSLog(appSupportDir);
return [NSURL URLWithString:appSupportDir];}


- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{

// assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
if(!success){
    NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
}
return success;
}
```

But at the end, I just get an error:
[1535:60b] Error excluding (null) from backup (null);

Is there anything Im missing?
For a start, what's bugging me is - is there any line of code I should write to even tell that I want all my side in that specific folder, that I later want to skip backing up?
if I should do that, where should I?
AppDelegate.m or somewhere else?

This part of AppDevelopment is something I never came across before, so I'm really lost in here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't create your directory anywhere. Before calling `addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL` add a verification if the directory is there and create it if needed.

```
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] isDirectory:NULL]) {
            NSError *error = nil;        
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
            if (error){
                 //Something went wrong
            }
    }
```

Comment: It ends up with //Something went wrong.
I edited my question so you can see how my code looks like, after I did what you suggested

Comment: @Stebra add a log to see what's wrong : `NSLog(@"%@",error);`

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)"

Comment: As far as I know, that means that he is making a folder that already exists..but if it exists, why can't I exclude it from backup later ?!